# 22.04.3 System randomly hangs [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request

Tags: intel-graphics, freeze

My system hangs completely every few weeks. The last line on the screen each time is:

`[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.`

This line is never actually recorded in the logs and is only visible on the screen before I'm forced to power the system off. I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting. The crashes appear to coincide with Plex hardware transcoding using Intel QSV via /dev/dri/renderD128

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- ASUS P10S-M-WS-IPMI-0
- Intel Xeon CPU E3-1225 v6 @ 3.30GHz
- 64GB RAM

Please let me know what other information might be helpful or if you have a fix in mind. Thanks!

Comment: What I understand is that your system's GUI is hanging, but you still can access command line, using Ctrl+Alt+F4, etc.

Comment: This is a headless system and no longer responds to SSH, Sysreq or any combination of keys. It is a complete freeze where the system is no longer able to even write the final log entry to disk.